Across function using a calculation with a third variable in R
Working with a set of data that has many different variables, each variable has it's own log data. The clients in this dataset can interact with many different things on the website. For example, they can interact with a post or they can access a page. Each time one of these events happens, an event time is recorded. I want to calculate total count, min, max, and avg events per day for each activity type simultaneously.
Example data is below:
participation <- data.frame(
  client_ID = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 098, 098, 098, 101, 092, 092),
  client_type = c("Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", 
                  "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type A", "Type B", "Type B"),
  event_date = as.POSIXct(c("2001-01-01 02:30:00", "2001-01-01 02:34:00", 
                            "2001-01-01 02:37:00", "2001-01-01 02:38:00", 
                            "2001-01-01 02:42:00", "2003-01-01 02:01:00", 
                            "2003-01-01 02:42:00", "2003-01-01 02:45:00", 
                            "2001-02-05 02:42:00", "2001-01-01 04:42:00", 
                            "2001-01-01 02:44:00")),
  post_id = c(111, 112, NA, NA, NA, 111, 111, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  page_id = c(NA, NA, 3, 7, 7, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 7)
)

I can do the calculations separately using many different counters, but I am wondering if I can do it all together.
I tried the code below but I can't figure out how to get the function to work for a third column (event_date). I need a distinct count of daily events per activity, not just distinct counts of the activity.
library(dplyr)

participation_count <- participation %>%
  group_by(client_type) %>%
  #summarise(across(c(post_id, page_id), n_distinct(event_date))
  #line above does not work
   summarize(across(c(post_id, page_id), n_distinct)

But what I need is a total event count (and avg, min, max) of each activity type per day.

Please share a minimal reproducible example of your data (not just a table but something we can directly paste into R).

Isn't this a standard combination of reshaping and grouped summarizing? (Links refer to the corresponding tidyverse functions, but there's alternatives like {data.table} or base R.)

Please update your expected output based on the toy data provided. (don't just make it up). How does the total differ from the average?

yes @I_O but I need the calculation based on a third column, so distinct count of event times for a page or a post, not just how many times that page (or post's) id occurs in the dataset.

So you'd reshape your data from wide to long, to make "page_id" and "post_id" one column of the same 2-level variable "target" (or whatever), along with their corresponding values in another colum "ids" (or whatever), group by any desired columns and summarize. Please add a sample table of how the output should look like (see @Edward 's comment).

Please read [MRE] and edit your post accordingly.
